# What does "()V" mean in a class signature?

Tags: java, bytecode, javassist

I created a constructor with Javassist which has no real method

```
CtConstructor c = CtNewConstructor.make ( argTypes, null, newClass );
```

When I'm trying to put out the signature of this class

```
c.getSignature();
```

I get

```
public Echo ()V
```

I'm confused what "V" means? I expected either public Echo (); or something similar...

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The JVM uses a compact way of storing method signatures, of which constructors are considered a special case.

For your example:

- `()` indicates a method taking no arguments
- `V` indicates that it returns nothing

The other parts of the scheme are:

- `B` - byte
- `C` - char
- `D` - double
- `F` - float
- `I` - int
- `J` - long
- `S` - short
- `V` - void
- `Z` - boolean
- `[` - array of the thing following the bracket
- `L` [class name] `;` - instance of this class, with dots becoming slashes
- `(` [args] `)` [return type] - method signature

For example:

```
public int foo(String bar, long[][] baz)
```

would become

```
(Ljava/lang/String;[[J)I
```

See the [spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#wp276) at Sun^H^H^HOracle's web site

Comment: Can you please tell me what `^H^H^H` part means?

Comment: :) No I know you meant to erase those preceding three characters. Thanks for the link! :)

Answer (score 7):

"V" determines the result type "void"

Answer (score 5):

V in a type signature means void type. Bytecode does not differentiate constructors from other methods (other than using special method name).